# Is writing parser the right way to solve this programming challenge?

Tags: parsing, language-agnostic

Take a look at this programming challenge.

https://gist.github.com/1083219

> We’ve built a new communication protocol that sends messages with a restricted syntax.
>   We need to write a function which determines whether a given message is syntactically valid or not.
>
> Here are the rules:
>
> 1. There are 15 valid characters in the protocol: the lower-case characters ‘a’ through ‘j’
>      and the uppercase characters ‘Z’, ‘M’, ‘K’, ‘P’, and ‘Q’.
> 2. Every lower-case character in isolation is a valid message, e.g., ‘a’ is a valid message.
> 3. If σ is a valid message then so is Zσ.
> 4. If σ and τ are valid messages then so are Mστ , Kστ , Pστ , and Qστ .
> 5. All other messages are invalid.
>
> Write a function in the language of your choosing to check whether messages are valid.
>   The input consists of a series of potential messages separated by whitespace and containing
>   only the 15 characters above.
>
> The output consists of one line per potential messages, followed by ‘VALID’ if the message is valid and ‘INVALID’ if it is invalid.
>
> Below is some example output.
>
> ```
> Input    Output
> Qa Zj    Qa INVALID
> MZca     Zj VALID
> Khfa     MZca VALID
>          Khfa INVALID
> ```

There are many ways to solve it including regex, parsing character by character. I am wondering what others think of how to go about solving the problem.

I think a simple parser might be the best way to go. First write the grammar and then implement the parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be able to do this with a fairly simple recursive string function `f`:

1. Look at the first character of the string
2. If it is a lower case letter, return the rest of the string
3. If it is `Z`, return `f(the rest of the string)`
4. If it is `M, K, P, or Q`, then return `f(f(the rest of the string))`
5. Otherwise, return the entire string

Then wrap this in a function `g` that returns true if f returns the empty string and false otherwise. Do this for each message.

This works because the grammar you described is a simple tree structure: Any node with two children is `M, K, P, or Q`, any node with one child is `Z`, and any leaf is a lowercase letter. `f` always consumes exactly one node on the tree and returns the rest of the tree (including siblings), and returns a nonempty string on a malformed tree.